# Trouble using 'with' binding with a named template

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to knockout. I have a viewmodel with a list of trades.  I'm showing  a couple of fields from them in a    on the left of my page. When the user hovers over one of them, i want to show details of the tade on the right of the page. 
My  viewmodel looks like this

```
 var self = this;
    self.selectedTrade = ko.observable(null);
    self.trades = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectTrade = function (item) {
        self.selectedTrade(item);
    }
```

When a user hovers over an item in the left, it calls selecttrade  so the selectedTrade has a vaulue. I have a div on the right bound to selectedTrade.

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tradelist', foreach: trades}" />
<script id='tradelist' type="text/html">
 <li> <span data-bind="text: Cname, event: { mouseover: $root.selectTrade } "/>&nbsp <span data-bind="text: Cparty"/></li>
</script>
</div>
<div data-bind="template: {with: selectedTrade(), name: 'displayTradeTemplate' }" />

<script id='displayTradeTemplate' type="text/html">

  <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Contract Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: Cname">
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

When i load the page javascript compains: 
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Expected identifier, string or number;
Bindings value: template: {with: selectedTrade(), name: 'displayTradeTemplate' }

anyone know whats wrong with that binding.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data:` instead of `with:` inside that template binding

Comment: Thats what i had orignally, but then when my page loaded I got an error that said CName was not valid. When the paghe loads there is no selectedTrade.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle, If I cjange the 'with' to a 'data' a get an error that cname is note defined. I appreciate you help. http://jsfiddle.net/russellgove/bRhUQ/3/

Comment: If you need to protect against null, then you can also add an `if` into your template binding.  It would look like:  `template: { 'if': selectedTrade, data: selectedTrade, name: 'displayTradeTemplate' }`.  The `if` is in quotes, because there is currently an issue with an "if" at that level in IE < 9, as "if" is a keyword.

Comment: OK , thanks. that got me by that issue. Now it displays the list, but when I hover over an item , I get a jscript error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot find template with ID displayTradeTemplate/  the new fiddel is at 
http://jsfiddle.net/russellgove/bRhUQ/7/

Comment: Make sure that you don't self-close tags like `div`, `span` and `ul`.  They need to be like `<span></span>` rather than `<span />`.  Here is an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bRhUQ/8/

Comment: Got it. Thanks Ryan.I just printed out all your articles on knockmeout.net. Hopefully after some heavy reading tonite, i wont have as many question for you tomorrow!